# GCP Cloud Asset API not enabled for different project

Tags: java, api, google-cloud-platform

I'm calling `searchAllResources` method from the GCP Cloud Asset API using the Java library (Kotlin) for project (let's call it) `MyProject1`

```
client.searchAllResources(
             SearchAllResourcesRequest.newBuilder()
                 .setScope("projects/MyProject1")
                 .addAllAssetTypes(listOf("k8s.io/Pod"))
                 .build()
         ).iterateAll()
```

I'm getting

```
PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud Asset API has not been used in project <MyProject2 number here> before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudasset.googleapis.com/overview?project=<MyProject2 number here> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

The strange thing is that I'm getting the error for a project that is different from the scoped one. This query is run for a couple of projects in a loop and all calls are giving an error for a single project. e.g. I'm calling the api for `MyProject1`, `MyProject3` and `MyProject4` in a loop but all throw an error that the API is not enabled in `MyProject2`.

Any idea why is that happening?

Edit: the credentials used is a service account, loaded like this:

```
val credentialsProvider =
            FixedCredentialsProvider.create(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(credentialProvider.getCredentialsStream()))
        return AssetServiceClient.create(
            AssetServiceSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build()
        )
```

Comment: What sort of credentials are you using, and what project are they associated with, if any?

Comment: @JonSkeet using a service account (see update). The service account is in MyProject2 maybe this is the issue. The api has to be enabled for the project that's containing the SA Thanks for the comment!